# Add to Jhipster generator AbstractServices and use them in ElasticsearchIndexService

Tags: elasticsearch, service, abstract-class, jhipster

we suggest an possible improve to jhipster generator future versions.
Is possible you add this abstract classes to the generator and when generator create services extends of that by default, then you reduce a lot of duplication code.

And improve changing JPARepositories list to AbstractServices list in ElasticsearchIndexService.

## When we use DTOs:

public abstract class AbstractCrudElasticServiceImpl, S extends ElasticsearchRepository> implements ElasticCrudMethodService { ...

public abstract class AbstractCrudElasticServiceImpl, S extends ElasticsearchRepository> implements ElasticCrudMethodService { ...

## When we don´t use DTOs:

public abstract class AbstractCrudDomainElasticServiceImpl>  implements ElasticCrudMethodService ...

public abstract class AbstractCrudDomainServiceImpl implements CrudMethodService { ...

## Detail:

All services extends any of these Abstract clases without methods.
Abstract clases contains generic methods, you only @Override in subclases when you have a particular behaviour.

And very important we add a new method reindexData in Elastic services that by default calls to findAll, then in ElasticsearchIndexService we call to reindexData of:
  => private final List servicesList;

Comment: This does not look like a question for stackoverflow, it's rather a feature request to post on https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues I'd recommend you delete it

Comment: Created https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11876